# How can I get the angle from a matrix

Tags: c, opengl

I got a rotation matrix like this:

```
1.0       0.0        0.0        2.07814
0.0      -0.809017   0.587785   0.0
0.0      -0.587785  -0.809017   0.0
0.0       0.0        0.0        1.0
```

How can i get the angle from this? If I apply the inverse, i get this

```
cos exp -1 (-0.809017) = 144.0
sin exp -1 (-0.587785) = -36.0
sin exp -1 ( 0.587785) =  36.0
cos exp -1 (-0.809017) = 144.0
```

But my problem is I know that the angle was 216.0 degrees, How do I get back that angle?

Comment: But -216° is the same as 144°?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're computing inverse functions <del>incorrectly</del> in a manner that struck me as bizarre. You should use `asin` for the inverse sin and `acos` for the inverse cos. You're computing the *multiplicative* inverse, not the *functional* inverse. Although here, it appears to be the same thing.

Use the `atan2()` function. It will yield the angle from the y and x values. It implicitly computes the inverse sin and inverse cos, and it checks the signs of both y and x to discover the correct quadrant.

```
 ATAN2(3)

NAME
       1.8 `atan2', `atan2f'--arc tangent of y/x

SYNOPSIS
            #include 
            double atan2(double Y,double X);
            float atan2f(float Y,float X);

DESCRIPTION
       `atan2'  computes  the  inverse tangent (arc tangent) of Y/X.  `atan2' 
       produces the correct result even for angles near pi/2 or -pi/2 (that
       is, when X is near 0).

          `atan2f' is identical to `atan2', save that it takes and returns `float'.

RETURNS
       `atan2' and `atan2f' return a value in radians, in the range of -pi to pi.
```

I assume we're ignoring that 2.07814 that's clearly not part of the rotation. `atan2(0.587785, -0.809017)` gives me 144.0 degrees. `atan(-0.587785, -0.809017)` gives 216.0.

---

Aha! Your matrix is "sideways" from what I'm used to. The 2.07814 part is just a translation, I think. Using this 3d rotation matrix as a guide,

```
1  0   0
0  cos sin
0 -sin cos
```

... leaves me just as confused as before. I keep getting 144.0.

---

*A confession.*

I glossed over the radians/degrees issue above, because I used Postscript instead of C.

```
$ gsnd -q
GS>0.587785 -0.809017 atan =
144.0
GS>-0.587785 -0.809017 atan =
216.0
GS>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use it with that Matrix? Sorry but I Do not know the function atan2(). Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, this matrix got a collada model. Using 3D Studio Max and turning -216 degrees. (sorry was -216 degrees)

Comment: atan(-0.587785, -0.809017) * 180.0 / PI = -144.0 degrees, atan( 0.587785, -0.809017) * 180.0 / PI = 144.0 degrees

Comment: You're welcome. I'm embarrassed not to have seen that `mod 360` so generously illuminated by @Antoine.

Answer (score 6):

To obtain the angle of rotation (theta) from a 3x3 rotation matrix (R) you can use the following formula:

> tr(R) = 1 + 2 * cos(theta),

where tr is the [trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29).

In your example the rotation is given by:

```
1.00000   0.00000   0.00000
0.00000  -0.80902   0.58779
0.00000  -0.58779  -0.80902
```

Hence the trace is

```
1 - 0.80902 - 0.80902 = -0.61804`
```

and the angle is acos((-0.61804 - 1) / 2) * (180/pi) = 144°

Thus the matrix represents a counterclockwise rotation by 144°. Alternatively, as 144 = -216 mod 360, it represents a clockwise rotation by 216°.